# Change values in a Python dataframe, based on values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data1 = {1: [1,2,3], 2: [1,2,3]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {1: [50,60,12], 2: [14,70,60]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Where a value is < 30 in df2, I want to change the respective value in df1 to a semicolon.

My current approach is to change df2 to values of 1 where > 30, and -99 where < 30, then multiply the dataframes, and then change negative values to a semicolon.

```
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: np.where(x < 30, -99, 1))
df1 = df2.mul(df1)
df1 = df1.apply(lambda x: np.where(x < 0, ":", x))
```

It works with positive values, though I'm certain there has to be a simpler approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If same index and columns names in both DataFrames use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and pass mask from compare another DataFrame:

```
df1 = df1.mask(df2 < 30, ':')
print (df1)
   1  2
0  1  :
1  2  2
2  :  3
```